# How to print octal value or binary value in ruby programming language?

Tags: ruby, octal

How do i just enter octal value or binary value to print in ruby as Integer
i tried that an it works but is there any other way?

```
puts '1011'.to_i(2) # => 11
```

Comment: _"how to print octal value"_ / _"how do I enter octal value ... to print as Integer"_ – I'm not quite sure what you are asking for. Do you want to know what [number literals](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Number+Literals) Ruby offers, how to convert a string to an integer (in a given base), how to print numbers (in a given base) or maybe something else? Maybe you could explain what your are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

A few ways.  You can either prepend your number with radix indicators (where `0`= octal or `0b` = binary):

```
01011
#=>  521

0b1011
#=>  11
```

...or you can use `Integer()` to either prepend those radix indicators to a string...

```
number = '1011'
Integer("0#{number}")
#=>  521

Integer("0b#{number}")
#=>  11
```

...or to supply the desired base as a a second argument:

```
Integer('1011', 8)
#=>  521

Integer('1011', 2)
#=>  11
```

There's also the `oct` method for converting string to octal but I don't believe it has a binary counterpart:

```
'1011'.oct
#=>  521
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
# Binary to Integer
# puts 0b(binary)
puts 0b1011 => 11
puts 0b1011.class => Integer

# Octal to Integer
# puts (octal_value)
puts 0366 => 246
puts 0b1011.class => Integer

# Hex to Integer
# puts 0x(hex value)
puts 0xff => 255
puts 0xff.class => Integer
```